# How to place my camera to fit a 3D GameObject?

Tags: unity, camera

In Unity Editor, when I select a game object and press 'F', the camera will focus on it without rotation and this game object is filled in the view.

I would like to know how the the camera position is calculated? I don't need transitions.

Comment: Do you mean editor's scene viewport or an actual camera game object?

Comment: In Unity Editor, when 'F' is pressed, the scene viewport will fit the selected game object. I mean I want to reproduce that 'fit game object' feature using my actual camera during my game play.